# Android Studio imageButton and switching to another Activity

Tags: android, listener, imagebutton

UPDATE:

I have 4 imageButtons and each one needs a "setOnClickListener" or similar.  Once the listener fires, I have an intent to take the user to the next Activity, which is currently just a blank page:

```
public void onClick(View v){
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NewSong.class);
startActivity(intent);
}
```

I started out with 4 Buttons, and had it all working, and then decided to use imageButtons instead for aesthetics.

I'm not sure what the difference is in "buttons" and "imageButtons" are, but you most certainly can't interchange them.  My best 'Googling' has not turned up any solution so far in understanding how to modify my earlier 'button' solution.

Any assist would be welcome,

Ed

Here is the MainActivity.java code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //In this next line, note that 'btn' will never be used, it's
        //grayed out in the "Button btn...", and in the (R.id.btn) it is 
        //shown in red font, indicating I probably need to declare a resource of some kind?
        Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);


        Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,    NewSong.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

And here is the activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:clickable="true">



    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:background="@drawable/new_song"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
        android:background="@drawable/loadsong"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_marginLeft="55dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="55dp"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What is the problem that you are facing?

Comment: Can you please explain your problem in more detail?

Comment: My problem is that I can't find the 'magic' code that allows me to use an imageButton instead of a Button.  I just updated my post with new information, code and some comments.  Thanks for any assist.

Answer (score 4):

ImageButton in Android is not a subclass of Button, but of ImageView, so you can't store a ImageButton in a Button variable. So you need to use ImageButton as your button object class. The method setOnClickListener is not static and should be set on the button object you want to use. Also the Button id you try to use is not in your xml (at least not the part you posted). So your code should read sth like this:

```
    ImageButton btn = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NewSong.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks!  That did the trick.  Now I'm going to set up a switch so I can handle all four of the buttons.  I truly appreciate the assist!

Comment: Glad I could help. Consider accepting this answer, so other users can identify it quickly.

Answer (score 0):

If you originally had buttons that were working, you may have forgotten to change the cast type. For example

```
Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn); //Will work.
ImageButton btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn); //Might compile, but will not work.
```

Alternatively, if you left the XML tag as a normal button
    `<Button android:id = .../>`
and tried to cast it to an image button, an error would be thrown. You would need to change the tag to `<ImageButton android:id = .../>`

Otherwise, I'm not sure what changes you made that would result in this going wrong. Further details as to the nature of the error would be helpful in solving the problem

Answer (score 0):

1. You should `ImageButton` instead of `Button`.
2. Must use `setOnClickListener` to Button object `btn` instead of Button `class`

**Update your `onCreate()` method as below:**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ImageButton btn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
    ImageButton btn2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,    NewSong.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Do something...
        }
    });
}
```

Hope this will help~